# Override old SD card on windows

Tags: sd-card, windows

I have a KODi installation on the SD card and now I'm interested in overriding the SD card with another OS installation downloaded as ZIP. This sounds pretty easy but I'm using a Windows 10 device so several parts are only avilable seperatly or just not displayed.

Comment: If you mean you don't care about what is on the card and just want to write a Pi OS to it, pretend it is a brand new card and use the normal means.  There is no need or purpose to formatting the card any particular way first -- all that will just be overwritten anyway as the image contains all the formatting data.  It doesn't matter what is on the card or whether it is new or formatted etc.

Comment: @goldilocks But flashing an image on a MS Window$ PC has never something to do with Raspberry Pi. I have voted to close.

Comment: Well, I'm presuming by "overriding the SD card with another OS installation" the OP meant *another Pi OS*, and we do entertain questions about creating Pi SD cards on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Specifically:

- *"overriding the SD card"* `---->`  **over-writing** the SD card ??
- *"several parts are only avilable seperatly or just not displayed"* `---->` ???

I will guess that you want to write a new image to your SD card using Windows. If that's not correct, my apologies for wasting your time. Here's one way to write a new image to your SD card:

1. You must ***un-zip*** (decompress) your ***zip*** file. There are Windows programs that do that - find one, and use it. Do not ask how to do that here.
2. When you have ***un-zipped*** the ***zip*** file, there should be an *image file*; for example, `2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img`. You will now ***write, or "flash"*** this image file to your SD card.
3. You will need a program on Windows that is capable of writing an *image file* to your SD card. [`rufus`](https://rufus.ie/) is one such program.
4. You must now insert your SD card into your Windows PC. It may have an SD socket, or you may need an adapter:
   [image: USB-to-SD Adapter]
5. Once you have the SD card inserted, use `rufus` to write your image file to the SD card. Afterwards, replace the SD card into your RPi, and apply power to boot.

Comment: current windows versions from XP onward have built-in zip extraction. No fancy features, but rarely needed for this application